# Convert PDF images to PNG using Automator

Tags: finder, automator, pdf

I want to convert a bunch of PDF images to PNG images. How do I tell Automator to resize the final images to a specified size (in pixels) like `100x100`?

Automator is also adding a number to the end of each file which increments each time I run the workflow.

1. Get Specified Finder Items
2. Render PDF Pages as Images
3. Copy Finder Items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the 4th part from Photos 'Scale Images' which did the job for me...

1. Get Specified Finder Items
2. Render PDF Pages as Images
3. Copy Finder Items
4. Scale Images

Best, Peter